# MVC3 LINQ database user definition

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

How to distinguish between users using built-in database that Visual Studio makes for users in MVC3 template? I am using separate database for my application data.

I have added code to Account Controller so that wherever a new user registers, data for the user is stored in the Users table as well.

Here is my database structure:

Users table
-UserID
-UserName
-JoinDate
-Password
-Email

Movies table
-MovieID
-Title
-ReleaseYear
-Genre

Reviews table
-ReviewID
-MovieID
-UserID
-Rating
-Description

I need a way to find which user is adding a review based on UserID.

Comment: Why are you storing user data in 2 places?  The built in Application Services databases is designed to handle sensitive data.

Comment: do you mean you need to linq code to query the Reviews table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo do not need two database for that, All you got to do is create your tables in the aspnet.mdf created by MVC, OR run asp.net membership on your database and point MVC to your database.

That way you will have it in same database and you can reference it via foreign key.
LINQ-SQL to that should be easy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I run asp.net membership on my database?